# How do I fix my system crashing randomly when Minecraft chat is opened?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, ubuntu

After upgrading to Ubuntu 22.04, I'm having an issue with Minecraft: The chat flashes multiple random colors and crashes my **entire system** most of the time. This also happens very rarely with held items.
Does anyone know if there is a fix?

I am using an Intel Integrated Graphics card (HD 3000) - Mesa version 22.0.1 - Minecraft 1.18.2

Comment: Do you have any mod installed?

Comment: Nope. I tested this on vanilla singleplayer.

Comment: this would probably be better asked on askubuntu.com, but you will need the [logs](https://minecrafthopper.net/help/guides/getting-minecraft-launcher-log/) from java and from the launcher so that people can see what is happening.

Comment: - Why would I need the launcher's logs?
- How do I get the Java logs?
- This is game specific.

Comment: Have you checked things like your graphics driver and java version? Perhaps make sure you are all up to date on those? Do you happen to have another GPU you can try using instead (or switch to using integrated graphics if possible)?

Comment: - Graphics driver's looking to be the problem- but if I can find a temp. fix I'd really be happy. Yes, I'm up to date.
- I'm using Integrated graphics as it's my only option.

Comment: Can you include information about the graphics you use? What driver version, what is the hardware (I'm guessing some sort of Intel graphics), etc? Also, what Minecraft version? The more the better!

Comment: - By Entire system I mean the entire PC hangs. I have to manually restart it.
- I'm using an Intel Integrated Graphics card (HD 3000)
- Mesa version 22.0.1
- Minecraft 1.18.2

Comment: Have you tried checking for memory problems and disabling background programs

Comment: - Checked for memory problems, no luck 
- There aren't any background programs at all

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu 22.04...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going to leave a (very) late update on this. The Mesa team patched this issue in the crocus driver, so it's fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pleased to say the people over at Mesa3D (the graphics library I use) found a temporary fix.
Running the game with the `INTEL_DEBUG=nofc` flag fixes the issue.

EDIT: This fix is no longer neccessary. See my new answer.

Answer (score -1):

Your system does not meet [Minecraft Java edition minimum requirements](https://help.minecraft.net/hc/en-us/articles/4409225939853-Minecraft-Java-Edition-Installation-Issues-FAQ#h_01FFJMSQWJH31CH16H63GX4YKE):

> VIDEO CARD: Integrated: Intel HD Graphics 4000 (Ivy Bridge) or AMD Radeon R5 series (Kaveri line) with OpenGL 4.41 Discrete: Nvidia GeForce 400 Series or AMD Radeon HD 7000 series with OpenGL 4.4

You've said you're on Intel HD 3000, which only supports OpenGL up to version 3.1. You will need to upgrade to a newer video card to play Minecraft, or you may possibly find an older version of Minecraft that might have lower requirements, though I couldn't find them documented anywhere so it may take some trial and error.

Comment: Mesa3D allows me to use OpenGL 3.2, which is the **undocumented limit** for Minecraft. It runs fine under it, it's not on there though.
Please do a fact-check before answering next time.

Comment: These are the requirements from the developers themselves and I find no reason to doubt them, not sure what more do you expect facts-wise. Maybe post the different facts you're alluding to? 

Even if we ignore the OpenGL version number, your video card is still below the minimum given. The reality is that what you're trying to do is clearly unsupported on your hardware and it's not useful to look for a magic solution that likely doesn't exist while ignoring the more obvious problem: Insufficient hardware. The hardware requirements exist for a reason.

Comment: - The hardware requirements are above the absolute minimum, which my system- barely- has. You can literally search "minimum opengl version minecraft" to get that the minimum for future versions is OpenGL 3.2.
- "Unsupported"? People with lower OpenGL versions can file bug reports and have them accepted. There is support.
tl;dr devs wrong, OpenGL 3.2 is the minimum and you obv. haven't looked into it properly.

Comment: @ErisStarmaster "The hardware requirements are above the absolute minimum, which my system- barely- has. " Sorry but no, your graphics card is Intel HD 3000, which is below the minimum listed as Intel HD 4000.
If you're confident that you know the game better than the developers themselves, I'm not sure how do you think anyone on Arqade is going to be able to solve a problem you yourself cannot solve.

Comment: If they'd accept a support ticket from you as you say, why not file one? Still, if your problem is that your car isn't running, I wouldn't bother fiddling with the tire pressures when your car is missing it's engine, if you get what I mean.

Comment: I filed a bug report. I provided the info, and they didn't close it for older hardware- indicating they provide support for the older versions of OpenGL. 
And, to be honest, there's probably a fix. There's a fix for most of these issues.
Next time, do some research. Look into it. The devs are often wrong.